# SQL query to find final overridden id in adjacency list / closure table

Tags: mysql, sql, adjacency-list, transitive-closure-table

I have an adjacency list table called `attribute` (which also has a closure table called `attribute_closure` mapped for ease of recursion).

Each entry in the `attribute` table is one of 4 hierarchical types, with each type able to inherit *and* override it's parent type's entries. The four possible types are, by hierarchy, `category`, `product_line`, `product`, `model`. So `category` has a tree of attributes defined, which `product_line` inherits and can at any point override, and so on for `product` and `model`.

This is pre-existing structure for a pre-existing application, so any suggestions to restructure are unusable :-)

So, the adjacency list `attribute`, has the following columns: `id, parent_id, overrides_id`, with `overrides_id` (if set) being a reference to `attribute.id`, same for `parent_id`.
If `overrides_id` is set, `parent_id` will always match the value of the overridden attribute's `parent_id`.

For each hierarchical type, there is a supporting table mapping the type to the attribute, i.e. - `category_id, attribute_id`.

**I need to be able to get back a full attribute tree, with all overrides respected.**

Example data (this specific example only goes to product level, but you get the idea). Please flesh out further with your own sample data as needed.

`attribute`

```
+-------+-----------+--------------+
|   id  | parent_id | overrides_id |
+-------+-----------+--------------+
|  6036 |      5931 |         NULL |
|  6069 |      5931 |         6036 |
| 30955 |      5931 |         6069 |
+-------+-----------+--------------+
```

`category_attribute`

```
+-------------+--------------+
| category_id | attribute_id |
+-------------+--------------+
|           2 |         6036 |
+-------------+--------------+
```

`product_line_attribute`

```
+-----------------+--------------+
| product_line_id | attribute_id |
+-----------------+--------------+
|              16 |         6069 |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

`product_attribute`

```
+------------+--------------+
| product_id | attribute_id |
+------------+--------------+
|         69 |        30955 |
+------------+--------------+
```

Querying a tree that contains the above attributes, should result in only attribute id `30955` being returned, as the other 2 attributes shown should be made obsolete by 30955.

As mentioned, I also have a typical closure table, which maps out `ancestor`, `descendant`, `level`.  Extra brownie points if you can include a result that uses the closure to return a tree with overrides having taken affect. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I ended up going with, was to build a second closure table which represented the hierarchy of the overrides (so similar to building a closure based on parent_id, but instead using overrides_id). This allows me to then query to find the entire hierarchy of overrides for any given attribute.

I had hoped to find a query-to-end-them-all, but going with a second closure table was simpler, better on performance, etc.